# How to configure our own Id server with Ionic vue 3(Ionic vue beta)

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, openid-connect, vuejs3, oidc-client-js

How to configure our own Id server with Ionic vue 3(Ionic vue beta) and show a login page and redirect back to our app after a successful login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after solving it my self by using InAppBrowser with the loadstart event listener and i followed same implicit auth flow with a openid config and a security service to handle the session.

```
const browser = InAppBrowser.create('myAuthUrl', "_self", {location: "no"});

browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => {
//my service call to create the session
browser.close();   
});
```